# Receiving assertion failure when using stacks

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare these symbols (, [, { in an arithmetic question entered by the user. When all symbols have a matching corresponding symbol, or does not have a matching corresponding symbol it responds to the user appropriately.

There are 4 equations used.

```
(((3 + 4) / {{999.7} - 9}));
Passed.
8 * 3 + 2 / (4) - 33 + 7 * 1 + 2;
Passed.
(4+3 - {2*2)}; 
Passed.
(4 + 4) - ({5 + (4 - 1/2)}));
Assertion 'stackTop != 0 failed.
```

I have found that by removing the pop for the symbol '(' causes the output to give the correct answer on the previously wrong equation as well as changing the incrementation, however, the program then doesn't output correct for the others. I having a hard time figuring out exactly what is causing the probelm and I am not understanding exactly what the assertion error means and how to go about solving it. Below is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "myStack.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    stackType<char> stack(15);

    char str[100];

    cout << "\n\tEnter your choice of an artihmetic expression:";
    cin.getline (str, 100, '\n');

    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        switch (str[i])
        {
            case '{' :
            case '[' :
            case '(' :
                stack.push(str[i]);
                break;
            case '}' :    if (stack.top() == '{')
                          stack.pop();
                          break;

            case ')' :    if (stack.top() == '(')
                          stack.pop();    
                          break;

            case ']' :    if (stack.top() == '[')
                          stack.pop();  
                          break;

        }
        i++;
    }

    if (stack.isEmptyStack() )
        cout << "Expression has matching grouping symbol";
    else
        cout << "Expression does not have matching grouping symbols";

    cout << "\n\n\t";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider a trivial test:  `)`.  How does your program react with just that one character in the equation?

Comment: `({5 + (4 - 1/2)}));` has an extra `)` at the end.

Comment: The shown program's logic is flawed. The third pass should really be an obvious fail.

Comment: Okay I see It reacts the same way with all the closing symbols, but not with the opening symbols.

Comment: I put passed as the program worked correctly with that equation, I know it the symbols don't match.

Comment: @CandicePinkles You failed to check for an empty stack when calling `stack.top()`.  Also, why do you keep going in the `while` loop if you find that the parens don't match?  You should be exiting the loop immediately once you discover the equation does not have matching parens.

Answer (score 0):

Calling top on an empty stack raise that exception.

Following input will call top at first

```
)
```